# How to light this type of basic, old fashioned gas-cylinder-powered gas oven?

Tags: oven, gas

My rented apartment has an old rickety gas stove, fuelled by a hose connected to a gas cylinder. No electricity is used at all in any way. This is fine because in this part of West Africa we get constant electricity outages, but I can't figure out how to light the oven part.

Every guide I can find online assumes I'm trying to light a sophisticated gas cooker with a fancy feature like:

- A pilot light, or some obvious recess to light first
- A self-lighting spark when you push the oven dial
- Some kind of electric indicator light or control system

This seems to have none of these things. It's basically just a tin box connected to a gas cylinder.

I can smell a little gas after having the gas on for a while, but no amount of using a plastic lighter near the obvious holes inside the oven actually lights anything, and I can't see any clues as to where the gas is coming from. Obviously I don't want to mess around too much.

Brand is Westpoint, it looks like it might have been made in the 1960s or 1970s, no clue about model. Here's a photo:

[image]

Comment: If you can get them "gas matches" are useful for this sort of thing. Basically a butane cigarette lighter but the flame comes out 10-20 cm from your fingers.

Comment: If you don't have long matches, and don't want to just drop them down the hole ... you can either light a wooden skewer (it helps to crush it or split it a couple of times first) ... or light a piece of strand pasta (spaghetti, linguini, etc).  Both also work for gas grills that have a non-functional starter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back when we had one of these, we used to turn on the gas, wait for a *tiny* while (I seem to remember 4-5 seconds), then drop a lit *match* into  the front center hole. That would light up the burners. I'd err on the side of too little gas until you're used to it, and it may take a few attempts

Mom was pretty good at it, but that might have been through years of practice.

This [video](https://youtu.be/tGHuUQRLcYE?t=14) goes through the whole process, though I could have sworn you didn't need to push down the knob

Comment: When you say side vents, do you mean the vents along the side of the base, next to the X? Or on the inside vertical walls?

Comment: My memory is of the ones on the horizontal surface along the bottom. The process in the video looks like it would match your oven, and suggests that you need to use the center hole, and a specific position. We've not had a gas oven for something like a decade tho ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek your mom's may not have a knob to push, but many gas stoves, and fireplaces etc that normally have a pilot light have a safety feature that shuts off the gas if the pilot light goes out. This prevents the oven from slowly filling with gas. You push the knob in while lighting the pilot until the sensor gets hot enough for it to leave the gas gate open.

Comment: @Escoce many gas stoves have that safety feature but no pilot.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I am sure many do.

Comment: I think that's how mine works, I didn't smell gas until I tried holding the dial in. I doubt mine has anything as sophisticated as a "sensor" (no electricity whatsoever) but it could have some kind of mechanical heat-based shutoff (bimetal valve coverring, maybe?), which would be a relief! Can't test it right now as inconveniently my gas lighter has just broken and nearby shops are out of matches... will do soon!

Comment: Success! Unfortunately I lack your mother's skills, and couldn't find a way to get the timing right in the three-hand task of holding down on the dial and striking a match, but I got it lit by removing the base of the oven, lighting the distributor thing in the middle directly while holding the dial, then replacing the base

Answer (score 1):

Is there a "broiler drawer" below the oven? That's the standard gas oven setup I'm familiar with (one burner, used both to heat the oven and for broiling in the drawer below the oven itself), and the pilot light is typically far back (or rarely in front) of that drawer, rather than being accessible from above. Either a "long match" or an arrangement to hold a normal match with a long handle is generally useful in lighting those.

Comment: I don't think so, there's a white panel below the door but it seems to be fixed in place, no handle, no obvious opening mechanism. Sounds a bit too sophisticated for my tin box! Good to know about for other such ovens though

Comment: Try lifting the floor of your oven, then? The two round holes in the center look like they would be for picking it up with, perhaps.

Comment: Under there there's a small area less than 10cm deep, it looks like it's for distributing gas, doesn't look like it's designed to have food in it!

Comment: I was thinking it might give better access to the pilot light...